# IE 8 - Slow Click Event Recognition - 100's Of Clickable Table Cells

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, delegates, cell, html-table

The problem I have is that the customers are mostly all using IE8.  With so many  elements on the screen, IE8 struggles with recognizing which cell is clicked or navigated to.  The speed is unacceptable so I'm looking for ways to improve click recognition speed.  I have installed a jQuery Pagination plugin which gives the user ability to change how many rows are displayed which improves speed some but not enough.

What made me ask the question is the fact that there is no difference in click recognition speed when using .delegation() vs .click(). in IE8, even though .delegate should be much faster.  The below JSFiddle is a representation of my biggest table, about 10,000 cells. It has 'click' and arrow key navigation enabled so you can see the stark differences in speed between IE8 and Firefox/Chrome/etc.  Also, JSFiddle in IE8 may have a hard time rendering the example.

http://jsfiddle.net/RaySuave/Q6vex/1/ 
(the jQuery code came from another posting on this site, I made a few mods to suit my needs)

The most slick failed attempt I have tried to address the issue is assigning the delegation to a fixed number of rows instead of the whole table in a pattern like this:

```
$(function(){
   $('table tr').slice(0, 5).delegate("td","click",function);
});

$(function(){
   $('table tr').slice(5,10).delegate("td","click",function);
});

$(function(){
   $('table tr').slice(10, 15).delegate("td","click",function);
});
```

FYI - Testing speed of jQuery event handling methods in different browsers
http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-click/41

WHY THE NEED FOR SUCH A HUGE TABLE?
I am converting large spread sheets that have been in the past populated in excel manually into a dynamic web-based site where the user can populate HTML Table Cells via cell click and arrow key navigation.  The cell values will be saved in a database. The tables will be accessible for viewing by all authorized personnel via the web-site.

I have all the coding finished including the jQuery for making the cells editable, vertical text for column headers, and writing values to the database via Coldfusion and MS-SQL.

Thanks in advance for any comments or suggestions.

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: According to the fiddle, it is 1.4.4.

Comment: Try dealing with less data at once. When dealing with such a large amount of data, it is usually better to do pagination using ajax requests rather than client-side unless you are ignoring IE6 7 and 8 compatibility. This will allow the client to only handle 10-30 rows at a time rather than trying to sort and paginate 10k rows.

Comment: @ Elliot, Yes, I am using jQuery 1.4.4

Comment: The customer has to have the ability to look at the whole table at once. I am ignoring IE6 and for the most part IE7. Even at 20 or 30 rows, IE is still too slow.  The click speed is pretty important because there a tons of cells to update, especially when the table is initially populated. After that, its just a few cell updates here and there.

Comment: have you figured out how to improve performance? I am also in an IE8 slowness situation with a large HTML file... no issue on any other browser

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps someone searching for slow ie8 issue: [How to force ie8 to repaint after adding a class to a dom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783840/how-to-force-ie8-to-repaint-after-adding-a-class-to-a-dom-element). When possible reduce number of elements and events on the DOM and use `[some-attr]` selector over `.some-class` selectors.