# IE8 only shows css content after event fired

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, gsp

I have quite an issue with the :after selector in css on IE8:

Relevant code:

```css
.required:after {
     content:" *";
     color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="loss-theft-case">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="250px" colspan="2" class="required">
                <g:message code="losstheft.case.naam.label"/>
            </td>
            <td width="175px" colspan="2">
                <g:textField 
                    class="bigInput border_box naam_disableable x-item-disabled" 
                    name="surname" id="surnameCreateCase" value="${customer.surname}" 
                    readonly="readonly"/>    
            </td>
        </tr>
<!-- ...  -->
```

```html
<div id="loss-theft-case-dialog" style="display:none">
    <g:include view="lossTheft/createLossTheftCase.gsp"/>
</div>
```

```js
var lossTheftDialog;

function createLossTheftCaseDialog() {

    // Define dialog to be shown.
    lossTheftDialog = $("#loss-theft-case-dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        dialogClass: "no-close",
        minWidth: 500,
        minHeight: 375,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        open: focusTabTimeout,
        title: "Aanmaken verlies & diefstal case",
        buttons: {
            "Cancel": {
                id: "create-case-dialog-cancel-btn",
                text: "Annuleren",
                click: function () {
                    clearMessages();
                    lossTheftDialog.dialog("close");
                    log(SUBMIT_CANCEL_LOSSTHEFT_CASE);
                }
            },
            "OK": {
                id: "create-case-dialog-ok-btn",
                text: "Aanmaken",
                click: function () {
                    createCase();
                    log(SUBMIT_LOSSTHEFT_CASE);
                }
            }
        }
    }).css("font-size", "13px");
```

(and this code opens the dialog:)

```js
lossTheftDialog.dialog("open");
```

Upon first-load of the dialog the red * is not shown. If you close and reopen the dialog the red * is shown. Other dialogs built a similar way suffer from the same issue.

Additional details:
When you click on one of the required fields the * magically appears. If you close the dialog (by clicking on the 'cancel' button), the very moment before the dialog disappears the *'s are shown as required. If you tab from one field to another all of the *'s appear as well.

Further info:
I can't link to a jsfiddle because that does't seem to work in IE8. I tried the above code but that doesn't gives a * at all in IE8. If I try it in the *tryit editor* it seems to work.

So, it seems to be an issue that is specific to a dialog in our project but I can't seem to isolate it. I googled and stack overflowed and tried various things all day now but didn't find the solution.

One path was using jQuery 'trigger' to simulate the clicking but alas.

Any pointers/hints/answers are greatly appreciated :)

jquery version: 1.11.1 (min)
jquery UI version 1.10.4

I *do* use `<!DOCTYPE html>` as first line in the page.

[image: This is how the dialog shows up.]

[image: This is how it should look.]

[image: This is after clicking some 'required' fields.]

This is how the dialog shows up initially: (first picture)

This is how it should look (and appears after closing & opening the dialog). (second picture)

This is the dialog after clicking some required fields: (third picture)

Edit: (reply on comment) The dialog is not meant to be dynamic; it should just show the required fields as required (with a red *) upon first load, but doesn't, and does so if you close and reopen the dialog or click on one of the required fields.

Update: Other screens which suffer from the same issue don't get 'cured' by opening & closing one screen.

Comment: Fiddles work in Internet Explorer 8, though *building* a Fiddle in IE 8 can be pretty difficult. I would suggest you build your Fiddle in a modern version of IE (or whatever browser you have available) and then share the /show URL. This issue sounds to me like a render-invalidation issue. I have seen similar issues.

Comment: Try something that would force the element to be redrawn. For instance, set the `background-color` of the `.required` when you hover over it. This may trigger the dynamic content to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *found* it :D

based on the usefull hints of Jonathan I googled a bit further and found: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783840/how-to-force-ie8-to-repaint-after-adding-a-class-to-a-dom-element).

I wrote a little help method:

```js
function refreshRequireds(){
    $(".required").parents('tr').addClass('z').removeClass('z');
}
```

and every time I open a dialog I added this line:

```js
window.setTimeout(refreshRequireds,100);
```

And now the *'s are (after a mere delay of 100 ms) *shown* :)))))

I hope others may find this post usefull...

S.